# Facebook Ads API Error - Ad Account is not enabled for usage in Ads API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

So im getting the error:

> The ad account is not enabled for usage in Ads API. Please add it in
>   developers.facebook.com/apps -> select your app -> settings ->
>   advanced -> advertising accounts -> Ads API. Account XXXXXXXX not
>   enabled for this application.

While trying to make a add/remove user from a custom audience. Here is my code:

```
FacebookAdsApi.init(access_token=access_token)
custom_audience = CustomAudience('123456789')
response = custom_audience.remove_users(
    schema=CustomAudience.Schema.email_hash,
    users=[
        'example@email.com',
    ]
)
```

But when i go to the App control panel the Ad Account is already added.

[image]

What am i missing? I gave the app access to the Ad Account on the business configuration panel.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to also manage the AdAccounts that are going to be access by this API on:

Products > Marketing API > Configuration

[image]

This solved the issue.